# How to catch moment the input box lost focus?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the event listener structure like below to do some stuff when the input box loses focus.

But it won't work. What event should I listen to, to get the moment the input box loses the cursor inside it (i.e. user clicks outside of it)?

```
document.getElementById('div inside which input is located')
    .addEventListener( 'blur',  function(e){
        if(event.target.className=='editInput'){
            doStuff(event.target);
        }
     } , false );
```

Comment: In your code you were trying to attach the event to the div containing the inputs.  Did you mean to attach the event handler on every input inside the div?  If so, please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The correct event is onBlur. Look at this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>element</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function message() {
        var text = document.getElementById("test").value;
        alert(text);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("test").onblur = message;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works and prints the content of the input when it loses focus. Maybe your error is that you attached the event to the div and not to the input?

Comment: Gonna try attaching events in another way. Thank You!

Answer (score 6):

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

input.onfocus = function() {
  this.className = 'highlight';
}

input.onblur = function() {
  this.className = '';
}
```

Comment: do getElementsByTagName() counts elements with display: none; ?

Comment: @lwiii Yes, of course! Setting a style property does not remove the element from the document's DOM tree (even if it is display:none) :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Setting a handler for the blur event using vanilla Javascript:**

You could set the blur event's handler for the specific element "test" in vanilla jQuery using code such as this

```
document.getElementById("test").onblur= yourEventHandler
```

You can use the event handler in your question without any modifications.  That's that part covered.  However, I believe there is more to be said here.

---

**The big picture:**

The blur/focus events on text inputs are among the least troublesome events to work with in terms of compatibility across browsers.  But if you are going to do any serious development I recommend using a framework such as jQuery, YUI, Dojo, MooTools etc.  These will both help you write nicer code and will shield you from compatibility problems.

Unfortunately, the reality web developers have to face is that of many browsers with similar, but not identical behaviours.  It is not enough to find a solution that *happens* to work on a browser we happen to be using at the moment we test the piece of code we have just written.  We need to ensure our code works correctly across all browsers our application is targetting.  So what happens if you suddenly discover that your way of assigning the blur even does not work on some browser for some specific element but another one does?  Do you go everywhere in your code and put if's there?  Are you sure you haven't missed anything if you go this route?  And then, if you find another problem with another browser do you add another if' and so on and so forth? Maybe you decide to define a function `setBlurEventHandler` that does what it says on the box and use it everywhere in your code instead of statements such as the above.  Do you do that just for the blur event or for pretty much everything you do?  It makes sense to do it for other things too.  Great.  You now have a framework for writting code that is compatible across browsers.  If all of us kept our frameworks to ourselves we would be spending a lot of time re-discovering and fixing the same problems. Enter open-source Javascript frameworks. You can just use them taking advantage of the hours of hard labour others put into them, but you can also contribute by reporting bugs, writing code and documentation. Doesn't this make more sense?  (Or if at some point in the future you are sure you have a framework based on some very clever ideas, however incomplete, by all means put it out there and see both what you can offer to the community and what the community can do for you ... )

To better drive this point home, let me show you some comments taken from jQuery's source.  As I said before, the blur/focus events on text inputs are among the least troublesome events to work with in terms of compatibility across browsers. But how confident are you that you are aware (or remember!) the various browser peculiarities your code has to deal with when the handling of even the most basic and least troublesome events comes with such inline code documentation?

```
// IE<9 dies on focus/blur to hidden element (#1486)

// IE doesn't fire change on a check/radio until blur; trigger it on click

// This still fires onchange a second time for check/radio after blur.
```

For the reasons outlined above I recomment against working with the DOM directly.

---

**A better approach using jQuery:**

Suppose you had a `div` called `formDiv` with three `input` elements only one of which initially had the `editInput` class.

```
<div id=formDiv>     
    <input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" />   
    <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" class='editInput' />    
    <input type="text" name="test3" id="test3" />           
</div>
```

Using jQuery, you could simply do something like (I copied the actual logic of the event handler from your code):

```
("#formDiv input").blur(function(){ 
      if(this.className=='editInput'){
          doStuff(this.target);
      }
 });
```

which I believe is closer to what you wanted to do, than other solutions here. (In your code you were trying to attach the event to the div containing the inputs.  I may have misinterpreted your intentions but I thought this was what you wanted.)

You can try this solution with this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r7tuT/3/

---

**Some parting thoughts:**

There are people that will tell you that this or that framework is better and they may be right.  I will only comment that jQuery is the most popular one and is pretty decent.  The choice is yours, but as I said I believe you should start using one of these frameworks sooner than later as it will improve the quality of your work, let you do certain things in a blink of an eye and change the way you approach problems.  When a framework or programming language does this to you, is a great moment in your life as a coder :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try `onblur` instead of `blur`.

`blur` is a method which causes an object to lose focus, whereas `onblur` is an event that is raised when the object loses focus.